# C++ Gnu C++ 9.2 support for concepts and constaints

Tags: c++, c++20

I thought of having a play with "concepts" and "constraints"

The same code given at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) does not compile in GCC 9.2 (C++2a) with the error below ...

What would I need to do to my toolchain to get this to compile ?

```
main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'concepts' file not found

#include <concepts>

         ^~~~~~~~~~

1 error generated.
```

Comment: You need top upgrade to gcc 10 or use clang if you want to use concepts.

Comment: Many thanks @NathanOliver